# sorting particular data from table php

Tags: php, html, sorting

I tried to sort the particular data from my database. I have done to show the particular data according to the user input from the first page. However when I tried to sort the table, I got some errors which are undefined variable

this is my code to show the data in table and sort the table

```
<?php
//connect to server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('no database');

//connect to database
//select the database
mysql_select_db("fak_databases");
//submit button
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $country = $_POST['country'];
}

//query the database
if($country == TRUE) {

    $order = "";
    $sort = "asc"; 

    if(isset($_GET['orderby'])){
        $order = $_GET['orderby']; 
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];  

        //limiting the possible values of order/sort variables
        if($order != 'wipo_applicant1_city' && $order != 'applicant1_addr1')$order = "applicant1_addr1";
            if($sort != 'asc' && $sort != 'desc')$sort = "asc";
                $sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='$country' ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($order)." ".$sort; 

                //here we reverse the sort variable
                if($sort == "asc"){
                    $sort = "desc";
                }
            else{
                $sort = "asc";
            }
        }       
} 
    $sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='$country'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('failed to run');
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row_counter = 0; 

    $icon = "";
    echo "<table  border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
    echo "<tr>\n"; 

    // first column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "wipo_applicant1_city"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }

    //print the result
    echo "<a href='showDB1.php?orderby=wipo_applicant1_city&sort=".$sort."'>City</a>".$icon;
    echo "</th>\n";


    // second column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "applicant1_addr1"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }
    echo "<a href='showDB1.php?orderby=applicant1_addr1&sort=".$sort."'>Address</a>".$icon;
    echo "</th>\n";
    echo "</tr>";

//fetch the result

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row_counter % 2){
            $row_color="bgcolor='#FFFFFF'";
        }else{
            $row_color="bgcolor='#F3F6F8'";
        }
    echo "<tr class=\"TrColor\" ".$row_color.">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['wipo_applicant1_city'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $row['applicant1_addr1'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>";
    $row_counter++;
}

Print "</table>";
?>
```

I got errors on

```
 Undefined index: formSubmit in C:\xampp\htdocs\fak_ict1999\sorting\showDB1.php

 Undefined variable: country in C:\xampp\htdocs\fak_ict1999\sorting\showDB1.php

 Undefined variable: country in C:\xampp\htdocs\fak_ict1999\sorting\showDB1.php 

 Undefined variable: order in C:\xampp\htdocs\fak_ict1999\sorting\showDB1.php

 Undefined variable: sort in C:\xampp\htdocs\fak_ict1999\sorting\showDB1.php
```

and when I analyze my code I think I got a logic error on the

```
 if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $country = $_POST['country'];
}

//query the database
if($country == TRUE) {

    $order = "";
    $sort = "asc"; 

    if(isset($_GET['orderby'])){
        $order = $_GET['orderby']; 
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];  

        //limiting the possible values of order/sort variables
        if($order != 'wipo_applicant1_city' && $order != 'applicant1_addr1')$order = "applicant1_addr1";
            if($sort != 'asc' && $sort != 'desc')$sort = "asc";
                $sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='$country' ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($order)." ".$sort; 

                //here we reverse the sort variable
                if($sort == "asc"){
                    $sort = "desc";
                }
            else{
                $sort = "asc";
            }
        }       
} 
    $sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='$country'";
```

because when I tried to to sort the table, the sorting function is trying to access the formsubmit again which is the the form submit is only accessed on the first page when the user choose their option.

is anyone know how to solve this?

my html code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Data Mining</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="showDB.php" method="post">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Foreign Agent Country</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <select name="country">
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="JP">Japan</option>
        </select> 
        </td>
      </tr>
        <td colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my javascript code

```
function SelectAll(btn) {
    var blnVal = false;
    if (btn.value == "Select All") {
        btn.value = "Unselect All";
        blnVal = true;
    }else {
        btn.value = "Select All";
        blnVal = false;
    }
    var d = document.forms["auip_wipo_sample"];
    if(d["auip_wipo_sample[]"] == null)
    {}
    else if (d["auip_wipo_sample[]"].length == null) {
        d["auip_wipo_sample[]"].checked = blnVal;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < d["auip_wipo_sample[]"].length; i++) {
            d["auip_wipo_sample[]"][i].checked = blnVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never check if $_get['sort'] is set.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld actually I'm using javascript to sort the table...I think if we are using javascript, we don't need to use $_get['sort']

Comment: How does your actual html-form and javascript code look like?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I have added the html form code and javascript code...

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem for your variables is that you forgot to initialize $country and that you need to check with e.g. isset() or empty() if the $_POST global value "formSubmit" is available.

Example code here:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

$country = '';

if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && $_POST['submitted'] === 'submit')
{
    $country = 'Pangea';
}

print $country;

if ($country == true)
{
    print ' => country is true' . PHP_EOL;
}
else
{
    print ' => country is false' . PHP_EOL;
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" action="test.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it is just the php const for "\n" (<br/> in html) - if this solution helped you pls accept. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code I see somethings that I've tried to explain why they don't work:
Then of course you should not use mysql_* functions because they're deprecated. I don't understand where your call is to the js function, so I left that part out for now.

I hope this is of some help.

```
<?php
//connect to server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('no database');

//connect to database
//select the database
mysql_select_db("fak_databases");
//submit button
/* skip this part. Only relevant to check name of submit button when having more submit-buttons in same form
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $country = $_POST['country'];
}
*/

//query the database
//if($country == TRUE) { 
if (isset($_REQUEST['country']) { //do like this instead (because country can arrive from link or from form 
    $country = $_REQUEST['country'];

    $order = "";
    $sort = "asc"; 

    //if(isset($_GET['orderby'])){ change to:
    if(isset($_GET['orderby']) && isset($_GET['sort'])) {

        $order = $_GET['orderby']; 
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];  //You're getting the value from $_GET['sort'] but you never check if it is set (like you do with orderby)

        //limiting the possible values of order/sort variables
        if($order != 'wipo_applicant1_city' && $order != 'applicant1_addr1')$order = "applicant1_addr1";
            if($sort != 'asc' && $sort != 'desc')$sort = "asc";
                $sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='$country' ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($order)." ".$sort; 

                //here we reverse the sort variable
                if($sort == "asc"){
                    $sort = "desc";
                }
            else{
                $sort = "asc";
            }
        }       
//} End of check isset($_GET['country']) should be move down to assure that $country is set 


    $sql = "SELECT wipo_applicant1_city, applicant1_addr1 FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='$country'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('failed to run');
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row_counter = 0; 

    $icon = "";
    echo "<table  border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
    echo "<tr>\n"; 

    // first column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "wipo_applicant1_city"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }

    //print the result
    //echo "<a href='showDB1.php?orderby=wipo_applicant1_city&sort=".$sort."'>City</a>".$icon; //orderby and sort is defined but not $_POST['country']
    echo "<a href='showDB1.php?country=".$country."&orderby=wipo_applicant1_city&sort=".$sort."'>City</a>".$icon; //change to this instead so country is passed

    echo "</th>\n";


    // second column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "applicant1_addr1"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }
    //echo "<a href='showDB1.php?orderby=applicant1_addr1&sort=".$sort."'>Address</a>".$icon; //orderby and sort is defined but not $_POST['country']
    echo "<a href='showDB1.php?country=".$country."&orderby=applicant1_addr1&sort=".$sort."'>Address</a>".$icon; //change to this instead so country is passed
    echo "</th>\n";
    echo "</tr>";

//fetch the result

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row_counter % 2){
            $row_color="bgcolor='#FFFFFF'";
        }else{
            $row_color="bgcolor='#F3F6F8'";
        }
    echo "<tr class=\"TrColor\" ".$row_color.">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['wipo_applicant1_city'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $row['applicant1_addr1'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>";
    $row_counter++;
}

Print "</table>";


} //End of check isset($_GET['country']) is moved to the end
?>
```